# How check if application is still connected to server using sshxcute

Tags: java, unix, ssh, connection

I am using sshxcute-1.0.jar in my java code to connect to server. After performing some task on server, the program goes to sleep (for 30-40 min) and when it wake up i need to know if the program is still connected to the server or not. If not then only reconnect.

```
//connect to server
cb = new ConnBean(srvDetails.getHost(),srvDetails.getUsrName(),srvDetails.getPwd());
ssh = SSHExec.getInstance(cb);
ssh.connect();
customTask = new ExecCommand("some cmd");
res = ssh.exec(customTask);

// sleep form some time
Thread.sleep(sleepTime);

if(isSrvConnected()){
      // Do something..
}else{
      //connection to server lost so reconnect
      ssh.connect(); 
}

Boolean isSrvConnected(){
  //How to check if app is still connected to server or not...???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Boolean isSrvConnected(){
  return ssh.connect();
}
```